# Will RepMgr supports different versions of postgresql in master and slave

Tags: django, postgresql, repmgr

For an application which is developed by **Django** and database is **Postgres**. Now we have to implement replication.
We selected **RepMgr** because it will supports dynamic partition table's replicaton. But we have different Postgresql versions in master and salve.

1. Will RepMgr supports different versions ?
2. We have to setup only specific databases in slave. Is is possible from RepMgr ?

Answer (score 1):

No, and no.

RepMgr uses PostgreSQL's WAL-based replication. That will only work with the same version of PostgreSQL and for a whole cluster. You'll probably want to have at least a vague familiarity with the PostgreSQL manual before implementing a replicated cluster.

If you want partial replication (one database or even a few tables from a database) or different versions check out trigger-based replication such as slony or bucardo.

Comment: In slony and Bucardo:
1. Cannot propagate ddl changes so they have to be manually done on the slave.
2. The drawback of the above is that dynamic partitioning does not work as it depends on DDL changes
3.Both uses trigger we have to give a list of tables to replicate. This can cause problems when new tables are added.

Comment: Well, yes, you'll have to manually duplicate your ddl. Once you start getting fiddly with different versions etc you're never going to find a replication system that does everything you want out of the box.